# Json Fetch not working got no output (source url)

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I want to make a script that fetch the audio url to an audio player.
But when I am testing first the script if it's working then I get errors.
Do i something wrong?

The api is working and if I change it from AudioUrl to Title it says undefined.

May anyone have a good code that's working or is this a simply fix?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  $.getJSON("https://api.omny.fm/orgs/56ccbbb7-0ff7-4482-9d99-a88800f49f6c/programs/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/clips/",
    function(data) {
      var student = '';

      // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {

        //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING
        // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
        student += '<p>' + $.Clips[: 1].AudioUrl + '</p>';
      });

      //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE 
      $('#table').append(student);
    });
});
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: large;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #006600;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', ' Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', 'sans-serif';
}

td {
  background-color: #E4F5D4;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<section>
  <h1>TEST</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. It is obvious that `student += '<p>' + $.Clips[: 1].AudioUrl + '</p>';` is not valid JS

Answer (score 0):

Several things, like no element with ID=table and invalid JS in the Clips[:1] statement

Here is a working version

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  $.getJSON("https://api.omny.fm/orgs/56ccbbb7-0ff7-4482-9d99-a88800f49f6c/programs/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/clips/",function(data) {
      $('#table').html(data.Clips.map(item => `<tr><td>${item.Title}</td><td><a href="${item.AudioUrl}" target="_blank">▷</a></td></tr>`).join(''));
    });
});
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: large;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #006600;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', ' Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', 'sans-serif';
}

td {
  background-color: #E4F5D4;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  font-weight: lighter;
}

table a { text-decoration:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<section>
  <h1>TEST</h1>
  <table>
  <thead id="thead"><tr><th>Title</th><th>Clip</th></thead>
  <tbody id="table"></tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```